# Getting a segmentation fault when running Release version, but not Debug version in Code Blocks

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, codeblocks

I am using Code Blocks:

```
Release 13.12 rev 9501 (2013-12-25 18:25:45) gcc 4.8.2 Linux/unicode - 64 bit
```

On the following system:

```
Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon (version 2.8.7) 64-bit
Intel Core i7-4790
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti
```

When I set selected target to "Debug" and run my code, it works perfectly.  I have run it many times without any problem.  But when I select the "Release" target and run the program from the command prompt quite often there is a segmentation fault.

My C++ program is about a thousand lines, and I don't know what part of the program is causing the segmentation fault. So I don't know which code is relevant at this stage (I will post some code here when I have more information).  It does make use of pointers and a dynamic data structure.  I am guessing that something is not being initialised correctly, but I don't know how to go about debugging the "Release" version.  I have not changed any of the compiler or linker settings from the default values.  What could be different in the "Release" version to cause this problem?

(Update) Following Nathan's advice I was able to isolate the segmentation fault.  There is a for loop, but under certain circumstances the upper limit (end index) of this loop was not being initialised, along the lines of:

```
void fnProc(bool var_val, int inp_val, int test_val, int st_idx, int lim_idx, int xarr[])
{
    int idx, end_idx;
    if (test_val > inp_val)
        end_idx = someFn(inp_val, lim_idx, xarr);
    if (!var_val)
        for (idx = st_idx; idx <= end_idx; idx++)
            xarr[idx] = 0;
}
```

I was able to fix the problem, by initialising the "end_idx" variable to zero ("st_idx" is always greater than one):

```
void fnProc(bool var_val, int inp_val, int test_val, int st_idx, int lim_idx, int xarr[])
{
    int idx, end_idx;
    if (test_val > inp_val)
        end_idx = someFn(inp_val, lim_idx, xarr);
    else
        end_idx = 0;
    if (!var_val)
        for (idx = st_idx; idx <= end_idx; idx++)
            xarr[idx] = 0;
}
```

Is it possible to get Code Blocks / GCC compiler to issue a warning when a variable has not been initialised like this?  I see there is a GCC option: -Wuninitialized, but I don't see this in Code Blocks.

Comment: Use some `cout` statements to mark blocks of code.  Once you it faults you should at least know what block it id from and then you and narrow it down from there.  But you are right.  Most likely this means your code has some sort of UB in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get Code Blocks / GCC compiler to issue a warning when a variable 
>   has not been initialised like this? I see there is a GCC option: -Wuninitialized, 
>   but I don't see this in Code Blocks

You can add any compiler options that are not available from the **Compiler settings** -> **Compiler flags**
menu by navigating from the workspace tree-view **Your Project** -> **Build options** ->
**{Debug|Release}** -> **Compiler settings** -> **Other compiler options**
and listing them in the text-box.

However, it is unnecessary to add `-Wuninitialized` in this way because it
is enabled by `-Wall` and is provoked by your code with the usual release build
optimisation `-O2` (or any higher than `-O0`):-

**foo.cpp**

```
extern int someFn(int, int, int[]);

void fnProc(bool var, int inp_val, int test_val, int st_idx, int lim_idx, int xarr[])
{
    int idx, end_idx;
    if (test_val > inp_val)
        end_idx = someFn(inp_val, lim_idx, xarr);
    if (!var)
        for (idx = st_idx; idx <= end_idx; idx++)
            xarr[idx] = 0;
}
```

With g++ 5.2:

```
$ g++ -O2 -Wall -c foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function ‘void fnProc(bool, int, int, int, int, int*)’:
foo.cpp:5:14: warning: ‘end_idx’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     int idx, end_idx;
              ^
```

and this holds good back at least as far back as GCC 4.4.7

`-Wall` is enabled from the Code::Blocks **Compiler settings** -> **Compiler flags** menu
by ticking item **Warnings** -> **Enable all common compiler warnings**.

In Code::Blocks 16.01 (which I currently have) even this setting is unnecessary
because `-Wall` is enabled for both Debug and Release configurations by default,
thus the warning duly appears in a default Code::Blocks console project release build
of `foo.cpp`:-

```
-------------- Build file: Release in deleteme (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler 5.2)---------------

g++-5 -Wall -fexceptions -O2  -c /home/imk/develop/deleteme/foo.cpp -o obj/Release/foo.o
/home/imk/develop/deleteme/foo.cpp: In function ‘void fnProc(bool, int, int, int, int, int*)’:
/home/imk/develop/deleteme/foo.cpp:5:14: warning: ‘end_idx’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     int idx, end_idx;
              ^
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

As far as I recall, `-Wall` has always been a default GCC option in
Code::Blocks for the 6 years or so that I've used it, but maybe I am mistaken.